# how to retrive posts where their category is same with current post in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have post and category many to many relationship where post and category model define correctly, I have pivot table to but no model for pivot table.

When I get one post I have the post categories to, $post->categories.
I want to list all post with current post categories, for exapmle if the current post have category of A and B, I want to retrieve all posts with category of A and B.
What is best and easiest way in laravel elequent for this purpose?

here my models if it help

```
class Post extends Model
{
  public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
}

class Category extends Model
{
  public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Posts::class);
}
}

 public function singlePost(Post $post){

    $postsWithSameCategory = ???
   
    return view('home.post',compact('post'));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the posts with the same categories
*From your example; posts with categorie A, B, A/B, A/B/C would be returned*

```
 public function singlePost(Post $post){

    $postsWithSameCategory = Post::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($post) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $post->categories->pluck('id'));
    })->get();
   
    return view('home.post',compact('post', 'postsWithSameCategory'));
}
```

If you want the posts with the exact same categories
*From your example; Only posts with categorie A/B would be returned*

```
 public function singlePost(Post $post){

    $postsWithSameCategory = Post::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($post) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $post->categories->pluck('id'));
    }, '=', $post->categories->count())->get();
   
    return view('home.post',compact('post', 'postsWithSameCategory'));
}
```

---

To also answer your comment, you can define a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) your `Post` model

```
public function scopeWhereIsRelatedWithPost($query, $post)
{
    return $query->whereHas(/** ... **/);
}
```

```
$posts = Post::whereIsRelatedWithPost($post)->get();
```

Comment: Than you, both worked but I dont' get the difference, any way. Is there any way to reach this purpose easier for example something like this, $post->categories->posts

Comment: I have updated the answer with an easier way of getting the posts than repeating the query.